# If in all satisfying assignments all pair of variables can take all possible values is this tautology?

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I suppose this is both easy and false.

Let $\phi$ be propositional boolean formula on variables
$x_1 \ldots x_n$.

Suppose in all satisfying assignments of $\phi$,
all pairs of variables $(x_i,x_j),i \ne j$ can take all possible
values, i.e. any of $\{(F,F),(F,T),(T,F),(T,T)\}$.

> Is $\phi$ tautology?

In case the answer is negative, is there simple characterization
of those $\phi$ which are not tautologies?

Comment: $(x \lor y \lor z)$ is a counterexample. Don't know about a characterization.

Comment: Your condition can be restated as: the VC dimension of the set of satisfying assignments is at least 2.

Answer (score 4):

The *VC dimension* of a set $S \in \{0,1\}^n$ is the maximal $d$ such that for all $i_1 < \cdots < i_d \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and all $b_1,\ldots,b_d \in \{0,1\}$, there is a point $x \in S$ such that $x_{i_1} = b_1,\ldots,x_{i_d} = b_d$. Your condition states that the VC dimension of the set of satisfying assignment of a formula is at least $2$. The formula is a tautology if the VC dimension is $n$. There are sets of arbitrary VC dimension, so even if you replace pairs by larger tuples, your conclusion would still be wrong.

Comment: For a concrete example, try $x_1 \lor \cdots \lor x_{d+1}$, whose solution set has VC dimension $d$.